# Incorrect icon of Time Capsule in Finder

Tags: macos, mac, icons, time-capsule

Have a little perfectionistic problem: quite often in Finder Time Capsule's icon not displayed correctly, when I click on it - becomes normal, what's the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's one of the bugs which Mavericks 10.9.4 has. So you can't do anything beside waiting and hoping, that apple will fix this issue in a future update. (by [c0dev](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/59151/c0dev))